# Detect HTTPS in GWT client code

Tags: gwt

I'd like the view implementation for my login page to detect if its page has been downloaded via HTTPS. Then it could warn that login won't work unless the whole site is served via HTTPS, due to my checks on the server side and due to it being generally unwise. And it could avoid sending any password via regular HTTP.

Is there any way to do this in GWT client code without writing some Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This test should do it:

[Window.Location.getProtocol()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#getProtocol%28%29).equals("https")

Comment: Some browsers return "https:"

Answer (score 0):

A probably better alternative would be to write a redirect to https rule (on the server side) as soon as your user hits your login page, this way you force your users to be https from the start of the login process, before you send to your server any username/password, hence they are guaranteed to be encrypted.

Comment: Thanks, but I assume that's something I can't control as the developer of the software itself. And if https is not configured properly on the server then the user/admin will see an error message that's less obvious about what the real problem is. I'd rather just show a simple "You have not configured it properly" message.